# doc.documentElement() does not return root element?

Tags: xml, qt

I am currently working on a XML parser and I am using Qt to make it. Actually I have coded lots of things and functions but now I got a weird problem. When I make;

```
QDomElement root = doc.documentElement();
```

It never return root element. I debugged it and I can see doc has a value but never returns root element. What can be the problem ?

Thank you all

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you show. You need to show more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created an empty QDomDocument it has no root element.  You need to create one:

```
QDomElement root = doc.createElement("myroot");
doc.appendChild(root);
```

Comment: If there's no documentElement(), then the document didn't manage to parse whatever input you gave it.  Check the return value of setContent().